# How to Upgrade or Deploy in Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9

I am a **Magento 2** Developer but some work i start study on **magento 1** so please tell me the following command of magento 2 instead used in magento 1.

=>setup:upgrade

=>setup:static-content:deploy -f.

=>indexer:reindex

=>di:compile

Comment: There are no cli commands for Magento 1, may I know what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: i create a module by a online toturial but its not show in admin panel,which command is need to show it

Comment: in magento 2 we run deploy command

Comment: just remove cache session folder from var folder and login again in admin

Comment: okay i will try

Answer (score 0):

No command needed for deploy magento 1. In magento 1 deployment concept is not used like Magento 2